# Winding Number of Linear Map

Tags: real-analysis, integration, algebraic-topology, curves, winding-number

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a linear map, represented by a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$, with non-zero determinant.

Further, define the path $\gamma:[0;1]\to \mathbb{R}^2$,
$$\gamma(t):=f\Big(\big(\cos{(2\pi t)},\sin{(2\pi t)}\big)\Big)$$

I must find the winding number of $\gamma$ at $0$.

We have seen that
$$ W(\gamma,0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\gamma \frac{-ydx+xdy}{x^2+y^2} $$
but I'm not sure about how to apply this formula.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only linear maps which produce a path $\gamma$ with values in $S^1$ are the orthogonal maps.  More generally, the linear maps producing a path $\gamma$ not going through $0$ are the linear isomorphism (which are characterized by $\det A \ne 0$). Fot these you get $\gamma : [0,1] \to \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}$ and you can divide by $\lVert \gamma(t) \rVert$ to get a  path with values in $S^1$.

Answer (score 0):

**It is doubtful however that $\gamma$ takes values in $\mathbb{S}^1$ if $A$ is an arbitrary matrix.** So, there is some information that you probably forgot to mention.

Anyway...

If $A=\begin{pmatrix}a & b \cr c & d\end{pmatrix}$, then $f((x,y))=(ax+by,cx+dy)$.

Next, write $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ in terms of $a,b,c,d$, and just use the definition of an integral along a path $\gamma$. You will be reduced to compute an standard integral of a function in the  variable $t$.

Comment: I was getting ready to add, it is not clear (in fact, false) that this would define a loop in $S^1$.

Comment: The $\mathbb{S}^1$ actually was a typo, sorry for that! I edited my question.